# QLayout in QWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making a grid for my futur game with QT.

I have some thing wrong with the QGridlayout:

This is my Grid constructor:

```
                                Grid::Grid(QWidget *parent) :
        QWidget(parent),
        m_grid(new Cell**[Y_MAX])
{
    QGridLayout             *layout = new QGridLayout(this);
    int                     x;
    int                     y;

    for (y = 0; y < Y_MAX; y++)
    {
        m_grid[y] = new Cell*[X_MAX];
        for (x = 0; x < X_MAX; x++)
        {
            m_grid[y][x] = new Cell(x, y, this);
            layout->addWidget(m_grid[y][x], y, x);
        }
    }
    this->setLayout(layout);
}
```

[image]

As you can see, all of cells are in the grid

You will say ok, but what wrong? **The issue is when the programme is starting this is my grid**:

[image]

To show cells I need to resize the window... Why? ...

Can you help me please :)

Thank you for your time

Ps: add class Cell

Maybe that can from here no ?

```
                                Cell::Cell(const int x, const int y, QWidget *parent) :
        QWidget(parent),
        m_x(x),
        m_y(y),
        m_btn(new QPushButton("", this))
{
    m_btn->setFixedSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    m_btn->setFlat(true);
    m_btn->setEnabled(false);
    m_btn->setStyleSheet("border:1px solid #000000;border-radius: 13px;background-color: white;");
    QObject::connect(m_btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(selected()));
}
```

Comment: Dunno if it's causing the problem or not, but the `this->setLayout()` line at the end of your constructor is unnecessary and can be removed.  (The layout is set implicitly when you pass `this` to the QGridLayout constructor)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's same with or without **this->setLayout()**

Comment: this->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding); 
    layout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter);

Comment: @Azuraul 
if you want help you should provide a decent [mcve] :)

Answer (score 0):

Your custom widget, `Cell`, needs to have the correct [size hint][1] at show time.
 See

> sizeHint : const QSize
>
> This property holds the recommended size for the widget
>
> If the value of this property is an invalid size, no size is
>   recommended.
>
> The default implementation of sizeHint() returns an invalid size if
>   there is no layout for this widget, and returns the layout's preferred
>   size otherwise.